# C++: expected lots of misses: map vs unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map

I am unfamiliar with tools in `C++`. Please pardon me if this question sounds dump.

From the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) of `map.find()`, the complexity is `O(log(N))`. This seems to suggest the tree structure in the implementation.

From the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/) of `unordered_map.find()`, the average-complexity is constant while worst-case is `O(N)`. This seems like a hash-table.

I am looking for a kind of map that allows me to:

1. pre-allocate memory i.e. I know *exactly* how many items will go into the map
2. have fine performance when a lot of queries are not found in the map, which I know will happen in my use case

`unordered_map` satisfies (1) with `unordered_map.rehash`, but unfound queries may take a long time. `map` seems to have better performance for unfound queries, but without the pre-allocate-mem feature. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why would a hash table have poor performance on unfound queries? Generally speaking, unfound queries are detected quickly, since the hashes don't match anything in the table.

Comment: What's the size of this going to be?  If it's small the `std::vector` may actually outperform all the cache-unfriendly maps.

Comment: @NicolBolas worst-case `O(N)` suggests it is rehashing for collision, which means `map` may exhaust the table if key is not found.

Comment: @GuyGreer number of items is one million+.

Comment: @Mai: O(n) worst-case happens if every item you put into the table has the same hash code. It has nothing to do with rehashing.

Comment: @NicolBolas hmm...do you recall how `unordered_map` is dealing with collision then? I thought `O(N)` comes from trying to recover hashed object that collided with existing items in table.

Comment: @Mai: That's exactly what I said: multiple objects with the same hash code. This does not cause *rehashing* of the table.

Comment: @NicolBolas Perhaps my terminology is wrong, but somehow the implementation needs to figure out a new position in the table to put the object if there is collision...How would you recover the object in this case?

Comment: @Mai: You using `find`, not `insert`. `find` only finds items in the table; it cannot put any objects there.

Comment: @Mai: `unordered_map` typically handles collisions (roughly) by using a linked list (or related structure) chaining from each bucket. So if two items hash to the same bucket, it just appends the second one to the linked list; lookups of the first item will require a hash, lookup, and it's found immediately, lookups of the second item require one extra check along the linked list, and missing items that hash to that bucket pay the same cost as finding the second item (two traversals along the linked list, then giving up when it ends).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see! Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @Mai: There is no STL structure for it, but if you _really_ need predictable fast lookups, you may want to look at using a third party container that provides [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). There are [several third party implementations linked here](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/minimalPerfectHash.html); the goal with all of them is to make a build-once, check-many mapping with consistent lookup timing for both hits and misses, guaranteeing that lookup is actually `O(1)` under all circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a single, fixed number of items *tends* to imply that you're going to insert some specific items, then leave them in the collection until you're done with it.

If that's the case, I'd probably put the items into an `std::vector` and sort them. Then, if the distribution is *reasonably* predictable, use an interpolating search, otherwise a binary search.

As long as you don't have to insert/delete more items and retain the order, this is typically quite a bit faster than a tree, even if you use a binary search, simply because the data is contiguous.

Given that you expect quite a few misses in your searches, I'd consider a hash table (unordered_map) that you set to an extremely low load factor, so that the vast majority of the time, you'll hash the key, and if it's not present chances are extremely good that you'll land on an empty hash bucket, so you'll get an indication that the search has failed very quickly. You can set the load factor with `max_load_factor()`.

Answer (score 1):

A [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is good for situations where you expect a lot of misses. It's kind of like a hash table, except that it uses multiple hashes and doesn't actually store the items in the table, just a bit to tell you if the item is *not* part of the collection. It will tell you very quickly if there's a miss, then you need a secondary method (such as the one suggested by [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192215/5987)) to do a second lookup if filter indicates a possible match.